# TypeError in tic-tac-toe game in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I'm trying to make a tic-tac-toe game while trying to learn Python and keep getting TypeError and I have no idea why.
I have already looked at other questions similar to this (none with "NoneType") but I still don't understand where is my problem. I'm following a youtube tutorial and everything seems to check out, so I'm really lost here.

Here's the error:

```
  File "game.py", line 93, in <module>
    play(t, x_player, o_player, print_game=True)
  File "game.py", line 71, in play
    if game.make_move(square, letter):
  File "game.py", line 29, in make_move
    if self.board[square] == ' ':
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

And here is the code:

```
import time
from player import HumanPlayer, RandomComputerPlayer

class TicTacToe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = [' ' for _ in range(9)]
        self.current_winner = None
    
    def print_board(self):
        for row in [self.board[i*3:(i+1)*3] for i in range(3)]:
            print('| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')

    @staticmethod
    def print_board_nums():
        number_board = [[str(i) for i in range(j*3, (j+1)*3)] for j in range(3)]
        for row in number_board:
            print('| ' + ' | '.join(row) + ' |')

    def available_moves(self):
        return [i for i, spot in enumerate(self.board) if spot == ' ']

    def empty_squares(self):
        return ' ' in self.board

    def num_empty_squares(self):
        return self.board.count(' ')

    def make_move(self, square, letter):
        if self.board[square] == ' ':
            self.board[square] = letter
            if self.winner(square, letter):
                self.current_winner = letter
            return True
        return False

    def winner(self, square, letter):
        row_ind = square // 3
        row = self.board[row_ind*3:(row_ind+1)*3]
        if all([spot == letter for spot in row]):
            return True

        col_ind = square % 3
        column = self.board[col_ind*3:(col_ind+1)*3]
        if all([spot == letter for spot in column]):
            return True

        if square % 2 == 0:
            diag1 = [self.board[i] for i in [0, 4, 8]]
            if all([spot == letter for spot in diag1]):
                return True
            diag2 = [self.board[i] for i in [2, 4, 6]]
            if all([spot == letter for spot in diag2]):
                return True

        return False



def play(game, x_player, o_player, print_game=True):
    if print_game:
        game.print_board_nums()
    
    letter = 'X'
    
    while game.empty_squares():
        if letter == 'O':
            square = o_player.get_move(game)
        else:
            square = x_player.get_move(game)
        
        if game.make_move(square, letter):
            if print_game:
                print(letter + f' makes a move to a square {square}')
                game.print_board()
                print('')

            if game.current_winner:
                if print_game:
                    print(letter + ' wins!')
                return letter
            
            letter = 'O' if letter == 'X' else 'X'

        time.sleep(0.8)

    if print_game:
        print('It\'s a tie')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_player = HumanPlayer('X')
    o_player = RandomComputerPlayer('O')
    t = TicTacToe()
    play(t, x_player, o_player, print_game=True)
```

Edit: Here is the code from the `player` module:

```
import math
import random

class Player:
    def __init__(self, letter):
        self.letter = letter

    def get_move(self, game):
        pass

class RandomComputerPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self, letter):
        super().__init__(letter)

    def get_move(self, game):
        square = random.choice(game.available_moves())
        return square

class HumanPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self, letter):
        super().__init__(letter)

    def get_move(self, game):
        valid_square = False
        val = None
        while not valid_square:
            square = input(self.letter + '\'s turn. Input move (0-8):')
            try:
                val = int(square)
                if val not in game.available_moves():
                    raise ValueError
                valid_square = True
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid square. Try again')
```

Comment: why don't use just use a debugger, for example PyCharm has an amazing one, and you'll immediately know what's wrong.

Comment: It seems like either `o_player.get_move()` or `x_player.get_move()` function calls returns `None` to `square` which cause type error at `if self.board[square] == ' ':`. Could you post the code in the `player` module you imported?

Comment: @user696969 Just edited the post with the code from the `player` module!

Comment: I think you need to add the line `return square` at the end of the `while` loop in `get_move` function of `HumanPlayer` class since without that line, the function will always return `None` value

Comment: @user696969 That was it, I was missing that return! Thank you so much!